# Cumulative sum based on specified values

Tags: r

I have a dataframe containing one column (depth, z) in which I am trying to find the difference in the accumulative depth values based on regular depth values. I would like to create a new dataframe with 2 columns: the criteria value and its respective cumulative depth value, so for example:

```
z<-as.data.frame(c(1:20)) #Original depth values. 
crit<-c(5,10,15,20)       #Criteria for choosing cumulative z-values
crit.d<-as.data.frame(crit) #New dataframe to which respective cumulative values should be added
sum(subset(z, c(1:20) <= 5)) # This will give me the first cumulative value that I need.
```

However I would like to get the values for crit =10, 15 and 20. So ideally the new data frame would look like

```
crit     cumulative
 5          15
 10         55
 15         120
 20         210
```

Note: This is a simplified representation of my data, and calculating the cumulative `z` value at every x-th position won't work. A more reflective sample of my data set would be

```
z1<-c(1.2, 1.5, 0.8, 0.7, 1.6, 1.9, 1.1, 0.6, 1.3, 1.0)
z1<-data.frame(z1)
crit1<-c(0.5,1,1.5,2)

# A loop comes to mind, 

for(i in c(0.5,1,1.5,2)){
print( sum(subset(z1,z1<=i)))
}                               # But I get an error, because I cannot use integers

Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : 
only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables
```

Attempting with `cumsum`

```
 cumsum(z1)[seq(0.5,2,by=0.5)] # Which doesn't work either
```

Comment: you can create a new col using `cumsum`

Comment: @Metrics is right! For loops are evil! Use `cumsum(1:20)[seq(5,20,by=5)]` instead and get a slice at specified values. Or if you want your data.frame `within(data.frame(crit=seq(5,20,by=5)), cumulative <- cumsum(1:20)[crit])`

Comment: @ mlt, @Metrics,  Thanks for the insight. I came up with the simple loop `for(i in c(5,10,15,20)){
 print( sum(subset(z,z<=i)))
}`..But I will give the cumsum a try. Thanks once again

Comment: @user2507608 Why do you eagerly want to calculate the first part of the next sum again and again? You are making the next operation as O(n) instead of O(1).

Comment: @milt, ultimately I need the to get the accumulative differences per strata, to calculate the volume of water at incremental depths in a river (ultimately I want a depth-volume curve for a river channel). This was the most troubling part for me, and I did not want to explain the entire problem for fear of loosing focus on the part I had difficulty with.

Answer (score 1):

`merge` does this for you.

```
z <- as.data.frame(c(1:20))

merge(crit.d,
      data.frame(crit=z[[1]], cumulative=cumsum(z[[1]]))
)
  crit cumulative
1    5         15
2   10         55
3   15        120
4   20        210
```

Comment: Thanks Matthew, but if my original dataset was not a nice sequence of numbers, for example, `c(1.2, 0.3, 1.1, 1.1, 1.9, 0.4)` and my `crit.d<- c(0.5,1,1.5)`, then cumsum doesn't work

Comment: I think `cumsum` works in all cases, but `seq(max(crit.d))` is not always correct.  I'll edit.  If that's not what you're looking for, please edit your question.